# is the full image always computed when rendering a single pass?

Tags: compositing-nodes, render-passes

I've started learning the compositor.

[image]

I need only the glossy pass for now.

But I see that, when I render my image, the "full" image is rendered, then the GlossDir layer.
I was wondering if there was a way to render the GlossDir pass directly without having the need to render the image first.

Secondly, even if I've checked the denoiser in the render tab, my GlossDir pass is not denoised (so I added a Denoise node).  Is that logical ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaking, the passes are what compose the final image. The render engine isn't rendering "the full image" and then "the individual passes", instead it renders all the passes and then exposes the final result (what some other softwares call the "beauty pass") and the passes you asked to see individually. Sort of similarly to when you ask to see the individual channels of a picture.

As for denoising, the one you find directly in the render settings is only applied to the final image, not the individual passes. My guess is because most of the time, it's more efficient to denoise one pass that X amount of passes, and people who want to denoise passes can do it in the compositor like you did.

Comment: This makes sense..  thanks for the explanation..